# Passport Saml-> SAML provider return error after authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-saml

I am trying to use passport-saml for authentication but after getting authorized it through error `Error: SAML provider returned Requester error: An error occurred.`

When I click on login it redirects me to IDP login page where I provide username and password and then it redirects to my /login/callback function where it crashes.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler');

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./config/config')[env];

console.log('Using configuration', config);

require('./config/passport')(passport, config);

var app = express();

app.set('port', config.app.port);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(session(
  {
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'this shit hits'
  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./config/routes')(app, config, passport);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render('home',
        {
          user: req.user
        });
    } else {
      res.render('home',
        {
          user: null
        });
    }
  });

  app.get('/login',
    passport.authenticate(config.passport.strategy,
      {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
      })
  );

  app.post(config.passport.saml.path,
    passport.authenticate(config.passport.strategy,
      {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
      }),
    function (req, res) {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

  app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup');
  });

  app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      res.render('profile',
        {
          user: req.user
        });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  });

  app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    // TODO: invalidate session on IP
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};
```

passport.js

```
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport, config) {

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
    {
      path: config.passport.saml.path,
      entryPoint: config.passport.saml.entryPoint,
      issuer: config.passport.saml.issuer,
      cert: config.passport.saml.cert
    },
    function (profile, done) {
      return done(null,
        {
          id: profile.uid,
          email: profile.email,
          displayName: profile.cn,
          firstName: profile.givenName,
          lastName: profile.sn
        });
    })
  );
};
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    app: {
      name: 'Passport SAML strategy example',
      port: process.env.PORT || 3000
    },
    passport: {
      strategy: 'saml',
      saml: {
        path: process.env.SAML_PATH || '/login/callback',
        entryPoint: process.env.SAML_ENTRY_POINT || 'https://idp.example.io/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO',
        issuer: 'https://sp.example.io/shibboleth',
        cert: process.env.SAML_CERT || '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-sp.crt'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This is the error that I got on console and browser

```
Error: SAML provider returned Requester error: An error occurred.
  at /root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/passport-saml/lib/passport-saml/saml.js:677:31
  at _fulfilled (/root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
  at /root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
  at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
  at /root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49
  at runSingle (/root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
  at flush (/root/passport-saml-ex1/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

and this is the response that I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="http://sp.example.io:3000/login/callback" ID="_a41e13c5b43026d0b854985b77699814" InResponseTo="_0d7bb680083c3aa20048" IssueInstant="2019-01-08T20:26:24.715Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.example.io/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>
   <saml2p:Status>
      <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
         <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy" />
      </saml2p:StatusCode>
      <saml2p:StatusMessage>An error occurred.</saml2p:StatusMessage>
   </saml2p:Status>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: You need to check the errors at the IdP server - from the response, the error is happening there: "<saml2p:StatusMessage>An error occurred.</saml2p:StatusMessage>"  <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy" />

Answer (score 1):

Like Joe said you'll want to see what the IdP logs say, but you might find [this passport-saml issue](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/issues/234) helpful. Basically, if you don't specify an identifierFormat in your instantiation of SamlStrategy, it defaults to "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" which always resulted in a Requester Error for me. Setting identifierFormat to null resulted in a Success response from IdP.

That said, I later encountered some very frustrating redirect behavior on success which I won't go into, but if you find yourself getting redirected in circles between IdP and SP, [this passport issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/482) explains it well and offers a workaround. *which I still haven't gotten to work, so let me know if you do :)*